# how can i add a bar code reader to my rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing a project on rails where I have to scan the barcode from the client side and save the barcode data to the database. How can I use barcode scanner in webpage client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some javascript libraries for this purpose. Here are some of them:

- http://manuels.github.io/unix-toolbox.js-exact-image/demo/
- https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/barcode-generator-and-scanner
  (includes QR codes as well)

You can either provide a place where the user can upload an image with the bar code or use HTML5 canvas and the Camera API to get the code from the camera. In the last case, you should be aware of browsers supports, of the Camera API, canvas, etc.